# Plotly Vue TypeError: vue_plotly__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.Plotly.newPlot is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js, plotly.js

I am a beginner in Vue and Javascript

In this code constantly data is been sent from server through socket io , which are randomnly generated numbers

```
<div class="chart">
      <h1>{{ data }}</h1>
      <h1>{{ value }}</h1>
</div>
```

Values are updated in h1 for **data** and **value**, from the server which are random values.

But i dont know how to update the values in the graph.
Please help me out. I tried newPlot and react methods but doesnt work.

```
<template>
  <div class="chart-wrapper">
    <Plotly
      v-bind:data="data"
      div-id="plot"
      :layout="layout"
      :display-mode-bar="false"
    ></Plotly>
    <div class="chart">
      <h1>{{ data }}</h1>
      <h1>{{ value }}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { Plotly } from 'vue-plotly'
import io from 'socket.io-client'
const socket = io('http://localhost:8081')
export default {
  components: {
    Plotly
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: 2,
      data: [
        {
          x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
          y: [11, 1, 1, 16],
          type: 'scatter'
        }
      ],
      layout: {
        title: 'My graph'
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    socket.on('Cartesian_Pose', data => {
      var _temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
      this.value = _temp.X
      this.data[0].y[0] = Number(_temp.X)
      this.data[0].y[1] = Number(_temp.Y)
      this.data[0].y[2] = Number(_temp.Z)
      this.data[0].y[3] = Number(_temp.A)
      Plotly.newPlot('plot', this.data, this.layout)
      console.log(this.data, data)
    })
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import '@/assets/mixin/variables.scss';

.chart-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
}
</style>
```

I am getting
**TypeError: vue_plotly__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.Plotly.newPlot is not a function**

Comment: In your created hook try to look up in console - has your Plotly instance newPlot function

Comment: No its saying function not defined

Comment: May be this example will help to you https://codepen.io/rhamner/pen/MXgWqJ